# Reading multiple lines with bufferedreader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to read two lines from the keyboard using BuffereReader but getting unexpected results. This seem a very basic thing, still I can't figure out what is wrong? I am new to Java, any help is appreciated.

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    /*
     * Read input from stdin and provide input before running*/
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String line,line2;
    line = br.readLine();
    line2 = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("line1: "+line);
    System.out.println("line2: "+line2);
}
```

In the output I get following results:

```
1
2 3
line1: 1
line2:
```

I think it is not going to the second line of the input at all. What is the reason for this? The first line is terminated by a carriage return, so ideally it should move to the second line.

Could you also direct me to a good tutorial on reading inputs from keyboard in java?

Comment: Try and use `Scanner` instead, it is much easier to use for this kind of things

Comment: @fge Learning to use BufferedReader is about as important as learning to use Scanner.

Comment: I don't get the same results as you at all... it looks fine to me.

Comment: @jpaugh while I agree, using it for reading stdin is not the way to learn it

Comment: I just tried and I'll second Jon Skeet. No problems here.

Comment: Your code runs fine. Make sure it's compiled after your latest change and you're not running a previously compiled class.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am running windows 7 and using jdk1.7.0 for compiling. I was using JCreator IDE for compiling and running my code, which gave me the above reported output. However, if I use the command prompt for running the code, I get the expected output.